# Who are covering their tracks?

Tags: tenet

The Well-dressed man changing the clothes, Protagonist and
his team gather at a room:

> Protagonist: Can you defuse that?
>
> Swat 2: It's centrally synchronized. Are there more?
>
> Protagonist: **Covering their tracks.**
>
> Swat 2: Taking out the audience?
>
> Protagonist: They're just the cheap seats.

Who are covering their tracks?